# Facebook Graph API stream results that I posted on a friend's item are contracted with an ellipsis

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to search for a list of posts that the logged in user has made.  Facebook is kindly returning the data, but when the post was made on an entity outside the user's wall (even commenting on their own wall post) some status messages are contracted to 30 characters with an ellipsis.  I have tried both querying for multiple results and querying for the single result with the same... well... results.

I'm using the following 2 options as early test queries:

```
FB.api(
    "/me/feed?until=1321759969&fields=message,story,type,created_time",
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
);

FB.api(
        {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT post_id, actor_id, type, description, permalink, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND created_time < 1321759969'
        },
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
);
```

And both return a contracted result:

```
actor_id: "1234567890"
description: ""Whooah, what's this?  Looks..." on [User]'s photo."
message: ""
permalink: ""
post_id: "1234567890_10040428464859801"
type: null
```

I managed to track down the post within Facebook.com and it does not actually contain the ellipsis.  It correctly states: "Whooah, what's this? Looks like fun!"

Can anyone answer why FB contracts these results and how to make it not do that thing?

Comment: Looks like you are confusing the actual comment with the _notification_ another user receives _about_ the comment …